# The current path, newapp/1, didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django

I was greeted with this 404 when i tried to access `http://192.168.68.106:8000/newapp/1`

```
Using the URLconf defined in test_01.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1.admin/                                **working fine
2.polls/                                **working fine
3.newapp [name='index']                 **working fine
4.newapp testform/ [name='testform']    **NOT working
5.newapp thanks/                        **NOT working
6.newapp 1/                             **Not working

The current path, newapp/1, didn’t match any of these.
```

following the poll tutorial on the official doc
( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/ ), the polls app works fine. and the newapp index also works.
but when I try to expand into the app by creating new pages to it ( namely `testform/`, `thanks/`, `1/`), I get a 404 in response.

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .forms import TestForm


class IndexView(generic.View):
        template_name = "newapp/index.html"

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                context = {
                        /mycontexts
                        }

                return render(request, self.template_name, context)


class TestForm(generic.edit.FormView):
        form = TestForm
        template_name = "newapp/form_test.html"
        success = "/thanks/"

def thanks(request):
        return HttpResponse("thanks!")

def test1(request):
        return HttpResponse("good")
```

`urls.py`

```
from . import views

app_name = "newapp"
urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
        path("testform/", views.TestForm.as_view(), name="testform"), 
        path("thanks/", views.thanks), #I tried to use a function instead of class based view, but failed to produce a success result
        path("1", views.test1),  #I didn't miss a backslash here, it was intentionally removed to see if it made a difference

]
```

what have be baffled is clearly the framework understand that I do have the view and urls to `testform`, `thanks`, and `1`. but they are unable to be accessed manually through browser?

update:
the project's `urls.py`

```
"""test_01 URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
        path("newapp", include("newapp.urls"))
]
```

I do not believe its an issue with the project's `urls.py` as I can access the newapp's index page.

Comment: what is your main project urls.py conf ? (not urls.py module inside your app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your project *urls.py* file to this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
        path("newapp/", include("newapp.urls"))
]
```

and app urls.py to

```
from . import views

app_name = "newapp"
urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
        path("testform/", views.TestForm.as_view(), name="testform"), 
        path("thanks/", views.thanks), #I tried to use a function instead of class based view, but failed to produce a success result
        path("1/", views.test1),  

]
```

Now you can check https://localhost:8000/newapp/1/

Comment: changing the project url.py fixed it. I'm guessing the index page does not use the project url to build further down the url so it works fine, while the other does? hence it is the only one that works in the app? thank you very much!

Comment: yes the app has a separate basic url 

the urls in app are built on top of urls of the main url.py

So we should always add / at end